# getting selected select box text

Tags: javascript

i am trying to use like

```
var modelLength     = document.getElementsByName("FK_BrandID")[0].text;
```

when i try to alert this it prints only undefined.. is this not proper..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var index = document.getElementById("FK_BrandID").selectedIndex;
var value = document.getElementById("FK_BrandID").options[index].text;
alert(value);
```

That will give you the text of selected option in the select box. To get the value of select box instead, use `value`

```
var value = document.getElementById("FK_BrandID").value;
alert(value);
```

Comment: There's no need to fetch the element twice...also id != name :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByName("FK_BrandID")[0];
var modelLength = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nfYRU/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no element has a `text` property. Perhaps you are looking for `value`?

Answer (score 0):

Everything you read above is correct, the problem in your code was, the options word was missing. with this your code should work:

```
var modelLength = document.getElementsByName("FK_BrandID")**.options**[0].text;
```